# WebService SOAP Generator like WSClient++?

Tags: android, web-services, windows-client

i am using a WSClient++ Java for Android project to generate the classes of my webservice but the version is the trial soo the program only generate two methods. My webservice have only one but miss some classes after generating. Anyone knows other software like this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use DOM t generate your xml from WS.    (http://www.w3schools.com/dom/default.asp)

Also, generate the Web service using simple java program with the help of Apache tomcat and Axis2.   (http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/1.5/tutorials/BottomUpWebService/BottomUpWebService.html)

Then call these Web Service in Android using kSAOP library.

Regards,
Sneha